# What is the best practice for combining Docker with Python unit tests?

Tags: python, docker, unit-testing, continuous-integration

My Python project is deployed as a container, and also has unit tests. For Docker best-practice, the final image is supposed to exclude any dependencies that are only used for testing (like `pytest` for example). How should I exclude test dependencies while still running the tests?

One issue is that if I build my test environment independently from my deployment image, then those two environments may end up containing different versions of sub-dependencies. (Hypothetically if my project uses `rasterio`, and `rasterio` and `pytest` *both* use `attrs`, then installing `pytest` could alter which version of `attrs` is installed by the package manager. This suggests a bug could appear in the deployment image, without being present in the test environment.) If test dependencies *are* included in the final image, then the CI can be set up with successive steps like `docker-compose build`, `docker-compose up -d` and `docker-compose exec myimage pytest`. If testing dependencies are **not** present in the final container environment, how should the CI workflow be arranged? (E.g., if I used a multi-stage docker build and ran unit tests before the second stage, would I need to manually maintain a list of sub-dependencies to carry into the final stage?)

Answer (score 0):

**How to configure docker**
[gist](https://gist.github.com/Anexen/f1f2b815734a6877e426defdfa1b2fb4)
**How to use configuration**

```
# no dev-packages
docker build -t release .
# dev-packages + test config
docker build -t test-image --target=test .
# dev-packages + release config
docker build -t dev-image --build-args APP_ENV=dev .
```

**How to get requirements.txt and requirements-dev.txt**
Use pipenv or poetry to manage *general* and *develop* packages.
Example with pipenv:

```
pipenv install django 
pipenv install --dev pytest
pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
pipenv lock -r --dev > requirements-dev.txt
```

Details in pipenv and poetry docs
Source of knowledge: [link](https://youtu.be/eICh6hT9mMg)